# Ошибка [Error] expected primary-expression before 'double'

Tags: c++, double

Пишу простенький код и он мне выдает ошибку

> [Error] expected primary-expression before 'double'

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << pow(double a) - 2 * a * b + pow(double b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
double a,b;
cin>>a>>b;
cout<<pow(double a)-2*a*b+pow(double b)<<endl;
return 0;
}

Comment: вы не верно используете функцию pow(). Посомтрите какие ей нужно передать аргументы. и  cout<<pow(double a)-2*a*b+pow(double b)<<endl; это не корректно. cout<<pow( a)-2*a*b+pow( b)<<endl;более корректный вариант

Comment: Нужно что бы программа делала вычисление по формуле a во второй степени минус 2ab плюс b во второй степени.

Answer (score 1):

я точно не знаю что хочет автор но, если испраивть получиться более юзабельно

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <stdio.h>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
    double a,b;

    cout<<"input a"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"input b"<<endl;
    cin>>b;

    cout<<pow(a,2)-2*a*b+pow(b,2)<<endl;

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: а вообще можно и без pow()  просто  (a*a)-(2*a*b)-(b*b).  оно так и быстрее отработает.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему нужно вывести результат полученный из формулы квадрата разности:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << pow(a, 2) - 2 * a * b + pow(b, 2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```